# Can't figure out a good sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay, so i have three tables, 
`images(ID, name,..)`,
 `tags(ID, name, ..)` and
 one with the connections `image_tags(imageID, tagID)`.

Here's my problem, I'm trying to write a query that gets all the images that has **2+** specific tag IDs.

Sounds simple enough or so i thought. I know I can do it with getting all the images that has one tag and then check all of them if they have the other ones but the cost to performance is a bit too high that way.

Would appreciate any input on the matter..

Comment: Well i use a join for when i want all the images with just one tag but that doesn't work for multiple..

Comment: Post your sql code, post the results, and tell us whats wrong with the results you got.

Comment: See this question: [**How to filter SQL results in a has-many-through relation**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Would that work for you?

```
SELECT * from image_tags i1, image_tags i2
WHERE i1.imageID = i2.imageID
AND i1.tagID != i2.tagID
```

Comment: This looks like it's working :D
Going to be silly large queries when there are a lot of tags but i guess it cant be helped.

thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Looking at your comment replying @JaMaBing, it seems that you should get rid of the `GROUP BY`... But glad I could help :)

Comment: Yea, already got rid of it, does nothing once i add the tagID conditions ;D

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT images.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT tags.ID) as counter FROM images
LEFT JOIN image_tags ON (images.ID=image_tags.imageID)
LEFT JOIN tags ON (image_tags.tagID=tags.ID)
GROUP BY images.ID HAVING COUNT (tags.ID) >=2
```

Comment: Sorry i seem to not have been clear enough in my question, what i'm trying to get is all the images with specific tagIDs like tagID = 1020 AND tagID = 1016 not just a list with all the images that has more than two tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you want is this:

```
SELECT images.ID, COUNT(DISTINCT tags.ID) as counter
FROM image_tags it
group by it.imageID
having max(case when it.tagID = 1020 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when it.tagID = 1016 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

The group by brings together all the tags for a given image.  The having clause makes sure that it has the two tags that you want.  If you want *only* those two tags, then you can add the clause:

```
max(case when it.tagID not in (1020, 1016) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```